# How to get parent in a k-ary level order succint trie?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, trie, bitvector

I'm implementing a level order succint trie and I wan't to be able for a given node to jump back to his parent.

I tried several combination of rank/level but I can't wrap my head around this one...

I'm using this article as a base documentation :
http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120

It explain how to traverse childs, but not how to go up.

Thanks to this MIT lecture (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MVVvNRMXoU) I know this is possible (in constant time as stated at 15:50), but the speaker only explain it for  binary trie (eg: using the formula select1(floor(i/2)) ).

How can I do that on a k-ary trie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found my answer. This paper of Guy Jacobson explains it in section 3.2 Level-order unary degree sequence.

parent(x){ select1(rank0(x)) }

Space-efficient Static Trees and Graphs
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/aladdin/wwwlocal/compression/00063533.pdf

This work pretty good, as long as you don't mess up your node numbering like I was.

Comment: Interesting paper. Do those "directories" allow fast modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what `select1()` is, but the other part (`floor(i/2)`) looks like the trick you would use in an array-embedded binary tree, like those described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_heap#Heap_implementation). You would divide by 2 because every parent has exactly 2 children --> every level uses twice the space of the parent level.

If you don't have the same number of children in every node (excepting leafs and perhaps one node with less children), you can't use this trick.

If you want to know the parent of any given node, you will need to add a pointer to the parent in every node.

Though, since trees are generally traversed starting at the root and going down, the usual thing to do is to store, in an array, the pointers to the nodes of the path. At any given point, the parent of the current node is the previous element in the array. This way you don't need to add a pointer to the parent in every node.

Comment: Well, I need to go to the parent because I'll use this trie just for storing data. I'll use another data structure for indexing and searching.

But I'll still need a way to reference each way word in my trie in minimal space, this can be achieved by pointing to the terminal node and jumping back to the root.